# Unexpected error while trying to store user with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm relative new to node.js and sequelize and promises in js. But I don't understand why my program is giving me back my error message even when the user is created successfully.

My sequelize model, reading the docs and some answers here I added the hook to encrypt the password:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const db = require('../util/config');

const User = db.define('user', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  userName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(250),
    allowNull: false
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  type: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  }
},
  {
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: async (user) => {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
        user.password = hashedPassword;
      }
    }
  }
);
module.exports = User;
```

And this is the middleware that I use for storing the user

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const Patient = require('../models/patient');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

exports.newUser = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  console.log('REQUEST', req.body);
  if (errors.isEmpty()) {
    checkPerson(req.body).then((existPerson) => {
      if (existPerson) {
        checkUser(req.body).then((existUser) => {
          if (!existUser) {
            User.create(req.body)
              .then((res) => {
                res.status(201).json({ // 201 = OK, pero creado un recurso
                  message: 'Saved successfully',
                  data: {
                    generatedId: res.dataValues.id,
                    patientCreated: res.dataValues
                  }
                })
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                res.status(400).json({
                  message: 'Error while creating user',
                  DBError: error
                })
              });
          } else {
            res.status(200).json({
              message: 'The person already has an user, please login'
            })
          }
        })
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: 'No person found with that id',
        })
      }
    })
  } else {
    res.status(502).json({
      message: 'Data validation error',
      validationErrors: errors.array()
    })
  }
}

function checkPerson(payload) {
  // console.log('checkPerson payload', payload)
  const userType = +payload.type;
  switch (userType) {
    case 1: // PATIENT
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(
          Patient.findOne({
            where: {
              id: payload.patientId
            }
          }).then(user => { return user ? true : false })
        )
      })
  }
}

function checkUser(payload) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(
      User.findOne({
        where: {
          patientId: payload.patientId,
        }
      }).then((user) => {
        return user ? true : false;
      })
    )
  })

}
```

My middleware checks if the Patient (in this case) exists, then checks if the patient has an user, and if not it creates it. But the response that I get is 'Error while creating user', but if I check the database the user has been created successfully and I don't know why, Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem lies within the `then` clause. Instead of using `res` for both the `User.create` response and HTTP response, you should probably change it to something else, for example:

```
.then((createResponse) => {
    res.status(201).json({ // 201 = OK, pero creado un recurso
        message: 'Saved successfully',
        data: {
            generatedId: createResponse.dataValues.id,
            patientCreated: createResponse.dataValues
        }
    })
})
```